# Cannot make header div fit the whole screen

Tags: html, css, height, width

I am working on the project where I set the div of the header to 100% and the main container is also 100%, but the right and left sides are to filled by the header. And the top is also not at the very top, but I managed to fix it by applying -ve margin, but don't want to do that for the left and right sides.

Please help me fix this, this is the CSS and HTML code:

```css
@font-face{ font-family:'Junction';
 src:url('junction/Junction-webfont.eot');
 src:url('junction/Junction-webfont.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
url('junction/Junction-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('junction/Junction-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('junction/Junction-webfont.svg#webfont') format('svg');

}
#main {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 1.7%;
}
#header {
  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6978;
  display: block;
  font-family: Junction, "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -1.6%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Check</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <!--open main div-->
    <div id="header">
      <h1>Chekcking</h1>
    </div>
    <!--close header-->
  </div>
  <!--close main-->
</body>

</html>
```

*Note: I used embedded font Junction, which is not online. And also, I don't want to increase the width to 120% and make the left margin -ve. Please suggest another way*

Thank you so much,
Arthrax

Comment: it seems everything OK. Can you add a screenshot if possible.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the default margins from the body and other elements. A 'universal' reset is a good option althouta proper Reset CSS is optimal

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  }
```

```css
@font-face{ font-family:'Junction';
 src:url('junction/Junction-webfont.eot');
 src:url('junction/Junction-webfont.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
url('junction/Junction-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('junction/Junction-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('junction/Junction-webfont.svg#webfont') format('svg');

}

* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  }

#main {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 1.7%;
}
#header {
  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6978;
  display: block;
  font-family: Junction, "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -1.6%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Check</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <!--open main div-->
    <div id="header">
      <h1>Chekcking</h1>
    </div>
    <!--close header-->
  </div>
  <!--close main-->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

[as show in this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/qpf4m268/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `margin` with a `property value` of `0` to body

```css
@font-face{ font-family:'Junction';
 src:url('junction/Junction-webfont.eot');
 src:url('junction/Junction-webfont.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
url('junction/Junction-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('junction/Junction-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('junction/Junction-webfont.svg#webfont') format('svg');

}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#main {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 1.7%;
}
#header {
  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: #FF6978;
  display: block;
  font-family: Junction, "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -1.6%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Check</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <!--open main div-->
    <div id="header">
      <h1>Chekcking</h1>
    </div>
    <!--close header-->
  </div>
  <!--close main-->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers apply a default `margin` of `8px` to all sides of the `<body>`. Beyond that the margins of your `<h1>` are also causing your `#header` DIV to be pushed down. That margin will also cause a DIV below `#header` to be pushed down and add a "white" space between.

```css
body,
#header h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```